# How to query a Many-to-Many relation with TypeORM

Tags: typeorm

`Note` has a many-to-many relationship to `Subject`

**What is the best way to query it?**  I would *like* to write the following to get all the subjects on a give note:

```
  const subjectRepo = connection.getRepository(Subject);
  const response = await subjectRepo.find({
    relations: ['notes'],
    where: { note }
  });
```

but that returns ALL of the subjects, not just the subjects on the note.

Reln defined as:

```
  @ManyToMany(() => Subject, (subject: Subject) => subject.notes)
  subjects: Subject[];
```

-- and --

```
  @ManyToMany(() => Note, note => note.subjects)
  @JoinTable()
  notes: Note[];
```

The executed query is:

```
SELECT "Subject"."id" AS "Subject_id", "Subject"."name" AS "Subject_name", "Subject"."description" AS "Subject_description", "Subject"."createdDate" AS "Subject_createdDate", "Subject"."updatedDate" AS "Subject_updatedDate", "Subject"."notebookId" AS "Subject_notebookId", "Subject"."measurementsId" AS "Subject_measurementsId", "Subject_notes"."id" AS "Subject_notes_id", "Subject_notes"."content" AS "Subject_notes_content", "Subject_notes"."notedAt" AS "Subject_notes_notedAt", "Subject_notes"."createdDate" AS "Subject_notes_createdDate", "Subject_notes"."updatedDate" AS "Subject_notes_updatedDate", "Subject_notes"."notebookId" AS "Subject_notes_notebookId" FROM "subject" "Subject" LEFT JOIN "subject_notes_note" "Subject_Subject_notes" ON "Subject_Subject_notes"."subjectId"="Subject"."id" LEFT JOIN "note" "Subject_notes" ON "Subject_notes"."id"="Subject_Subject_notes"."noteId"
```

---

Note:  you can do this:

```
  return subjectRepo
    .createQueryBuilder('subject')
    .leftJoin('subject.notes', 'note')
    .where('note.id = :id', { id: note.id })
    .getMany();
```

But I am hoping for an approach with less strings, and explicit joining

Comment: ## Update 1 year later

After working with TypeORM for a year -- I have fully embraced the power of the queryBuilder and now is my first approach vs using finders.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. But can't this be done with one single *.find* function? Something like .find({where: { note: contains('id')}}) of sort.
Thank you.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The SQL you are trying to get TypeORM to generate is roughly as follows

```sql
SELECT *
FROM subject
JOIN subject_note AS jt on jt.subject_id = subject.id
WHERE jt.note_id = :id
```

### 1. This is not possible with `repo.find`

At the time of writing, there is no way to create a `where` clause on a joined table using `repo.find(...)`. You can `join` ([doc](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/find-options.md#basic-options)) but the `where` clause only affects the entity of the repository.

`TypeORM` also silently ignores invalid where clauses, so be careful about those.

### 2. Re-select the note entity

If you want all the `subject` of a given `note`, you will either need to use a query builder, like you noted or you will need to re-select the note object with it's relationships.

```js
note = await noteRepo.find({
    relations: ['subjects'],
    where: { id: note.id }
});
const subjects = note.subjects
```

### 3. Use `TypeORM` lazy relations

If you want to avoid re-selection, you need to use [`TypeORM` Lazy relations](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/eager-and-lazy-relations.md#lazy-relations) but this forces you to change the type in both entities to be a `Promise`

```js
// note entity
@ManyToMany(() => Subject, (subject: Subject) => subject.notes)
subjects: Promise<Subject[]>;

// subject entity
@ManyToMany(() => Note, note => note.subjects)
@JoinTable()
notes: Promise<Note[]>;
```

With this lazy relations, you will need to `await` for the linked notes to load before each usage, but you will not need to provide an array of relations to the `find` method.

```js
const note = await noteRepo.find({
    where: { id: someId }
});
const subjects = await note.subjects
```

Comment: seems like #2 is the best approach until you are forced to optimize

Comment: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/find-options.md#basic-options

Comment: https://newbedev.com/typeorm-query-entity-based-on-relation-property

Comment: For future references