# TypeORM - Search and populate Many-to-Many relation

Tags: typeorm

I have two entities `Tag` and `Photo`:

```
// tag.entity.ts

import { Column, Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
export class Tag {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id!: number;

  // Other columns
}
```

```
// photo.entity.ts

import { Entity, JoinTable, ManyToMany, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, } from 'typeorm';
import { Tag } from './tag.entity';

@Entity()
export class Photo {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id!: number;

  @ManyToMany(type => Tag, { eager: true })
  @JoinTable()
  tags!: Tag[];

  // Other columns
}
```

I need to filter results from `photos` table using results from `tags` table.

```
const photos = await photosRepository
  .createQueryBuilder('photo')
  .leftJoinAndSelect('photo.tags', 'tag')
  .where('tag.name LIKE :searchQuery', { searchQuery: 'nature%' })
  .skip(0)
  .take(10)
  .getMany();
```

The query above works fine: `photos` table records are filtered using `tag.name` column from `tags` table.

The issue is that an each photo entity in returned `photos` array contains **only** filtered (`tag.name LIKE :searchQuery`) `tags` relation entities. What I need is to eager load **all** `tags` relation entities for each photo. Is it possible somehow?

For example, with Laravel's Eloquent it's possible achive what I need with:

```
$photos = Photo::query()
  ->with('tags')
  ->whereHas('tags', function (Builder $query) {
    $query->where('tags.name', 'like', 'nature%');
  })
  ->skip(0)
  ->take(10)
  ->get();
```

Comment: You can add join of each relation, e.g. as you have made with tags

Comment: @ArtOlshansky I don't need to join other relations. My question was how to load all related tags for resulting photos. Right now it only loads tags which meet where clause condition from the query.

Comment: need help also here : (

Comment: @HuaenTan There is a good answer which adds additional details, though I don't think it's satisfiable: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52249577/2380334

Comment: i don't know,but this answer changes a lot code, so maybe waiting for a better way. My question is basically the same as yours

Answer (score 7, accepted):

maybe i found the answer

```js
const photos = await photosRepository
  .createQueryBuilder('photo')
  .leftJoin('photo.tags', 'tag')
  .leftJoinAndSelect('photo.tags', 'tagSelect')
  .where('tag.name LIKE :searchQuery', { searchQuery: 'nature%' })
  .skip(0)
  .take(10)
  .getMany();
```

the relative reference: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/3731